# $(window).scrollTop(..) not working correctly to put an element at the top

Tags: jquery

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lukeu3f8/9/

In this example, I have a long list with A-links which have the style `menulink` for specific sub-items (created in the onReady). My goal is to auto-scroll the page to put **Sub-Link #20** at the top. That would be **Menu Item 2.14.**

But on running the fiddle, Menu Item 2.1 is put at the top, which is not #20, it's #7. Why?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Append an index to each sub-menu item (the actual A tag)
    $('.menuitem > a').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('menulink');       
    });

    // Auto-scroll to .menulink #20 (sub-menu #20, should be 2.14)
    $(window).scrollTop($('a.menulink:eq(20)').offset().top);

});
```

Comment: The page cannot be scrolled further than when the bottom of the page hits the end of the viewport. Make your viewport less high and retry. And btw, `$('a.menulink:eq(20)')` is 2.15. Remember counting starts at 0, not at 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page cannot be scrolled further than when the bottom of the page hits the end of the viewport. Make your viewport less high and retry. And btw, `$('a.menulink:eq(20)')` is **2.15**, not 2.14. Remember counting array indexes starts at 0, not at 1.

Comment: Are you asking me how to resize your browser window?

Comment: There's no way to force whitespace at the bottom in an existing viewport? because that's what is required, put an element at the top by any means.

Comment: You could do something like `@media(max-height: 400px) { body { padding-bottom: 40em; } }` in your CSS. This would add an extra whitespace of 40em height in viewports which have a max-height of 400px. Play around with values until you see it fit.